# Xcode 8 - selecting Allow access to photo album with UITests

Tags: xcode, alert, uialertcontroller, xcode-ui-testing

I am running UITests in Xcode 8.  I have a test that adds a photo to the app.  When I first install the app I get the popup requesting access to the photo album.

Everything I have tried results in the 'Don't Allow' button being selected, which then breaks the test.  When I record the 'Allow' button click a UIAlert is found, but when I run po XCUIApplication().debugDescription no alerts are found, despite them being on the screen.

Has anyone found a way to get around this issue?

Comment: joern's answer is right. The reason you don't see anything when printing the debug description is because the view hierarchy has not updated since before the alert is shown. The view hierarchy will update when you next try to interact with the app (ignoring the alert) and it will discover the alert and run the interruption handler to dismiss the alert, then execute your interaction.

Answer (score 3):

To handle system alerts during a UITest you have to add a **UI Interruption Monitor**:

```
func testPhotoLibraryAccess() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    // when system alert is shown -> dismiss it by pressing "OK"
    // (the description parameter is only there for debugging purposes
    // so it can be anything you like)
    addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Photos Access Alert") { (alert) -> Bool in
        alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
        return true
    }

    // tap button that tries to open user's photo library
    app.buttons["Open Photos"].tap()

    // select "Moments"
    app.buttons["Moments"].tap()

    XCTAssert(app.navigationBars["Moments"].exists)
}
```

To make this work you have to make sure that the UI Interruption Monitor is added **before** the system alert is triggered by your UITest!